# UnitTest throws TypeError: componentFactory.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

We are using Jest to Unit-Test our application. Since we upgraded from Angular-6 to Angular-8 a Unit-Test containing a dynamic component is failing with following Error-Message:

```
TypeError: componentFactory.create is not a function

      at ViewContainerRef_.Object.<anonymous>.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (../../../packages/core/src/view/refs.ts:202:26)
      at src/app/something/something-detail/something-detail.component.ts:193:48
```

As far as I understand, the problem is located in the mock that we are using for this ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('somethingView', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
```

In the file for the unit-tests we set up this dynamic component as following:

```
// mock of the dynamic component
describe('SomethingComponent', () => {
   const makeMockComponent = () => ({
       instance: { selectLink: new Subject(), paragraphId: '' },
       destroy: jest.fn(),
   });
   class Page {
      dynamicComponent: {
         instance: { selectLink: Subject<any>; paragraphId: string };
         destroy: jest.Mock;
      };

      constructor() {
         this.dynamicComponent = makeMockComponent();

         component.viewContainerRef = {
           createComponent: jest.fn(() => this.dynamicComponent),
         } as any;
      }
   }
   
   beforeEach(async(() => {
      createComponent();
   }));

   // The failing unit-test
   it('should create', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
}
```

I am not able to debug this any further. I left out a lot of code, that I think is not connected to the problem. If further information is needed, please respond. Hopefully someone can help me with this.